# How can I solve date in flatMap is not working?

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, datetime, momentjs

My code like this :

```
  const result = {
    data: query.flatMap(
      (team) => team.players.map((player) => ({
        id: player.id,
        player_name: player.player_name,
        nname: team.name,
        date: moment(team.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
        description: team.description,
      }))
    )
  }
```

If I console.log(team.date), the result like this : 2022-07-01T00:00:00.000

I want to remove the time. So the result like this : 2022-07-01

I try the code but the result is date now. It is 2022-08-08

How Can I solve this problem?

Note :

If I try outside flatMap like this :

```
let isoDate = "2021-09-19T05:30:00.000Z"
let test = moment(isoDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
console.log(test)
```

The result : 2021-09-19

Why it's not working in flatMap?

Comment: Why not just use `team.date.split('T')[0]`?

Comment: I can't think of any reason why `flatMap` would change the dates. Can you show a sample of the value of `query`?

Comment: I suspect `team.date` is not what you think it is.

Comment: *"If I console.log(team.date), the result like this : 2022-07-01T00:00:00.000"* That's fine, that's the **input** of the process, not the output. Look at `result.data[n].date` where `n` is a number in the range `0` to `result.data.length - 1`. You'll see that it's a string in the format you've asked for. (For the avoidance of doubt: `flatMap` will not touch the `date` property of the objects in your array.)

Comment: @Barmar split is not a function

Comment: Then it sounds like `team.date` is *already* a date. That's fine, `moment(team.date)` will work just fine with that. (Although it's odd that what you've said is your `console.log` output doesn't have a `Z` on it. In most consoles I've used, if you log a date and it shows you a string like that, it uses UTC and includes a `Z`.)

Comment: Hi! Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/). **That said**, I think if you just walk through this with a debugger, carefully inspecting things as you go, you'll find the problem.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You must be new here :)

Comment: @Barmar **;-)**